# Why does $y(s)$ continuous imply that $f(s)$ with $f_l (s) = \frac{s_l + \max\{0,z_l(s)\}}{1+\sum \max\{0,z_l(s)\}}$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $z:\triangle^{L-1}\to \mathbb{R}^L$ be continuous. Define $f:\triangle^{L-1} \to \triangle^{L-1}$ be defined component wise as
$$
f_l(s) = \frac{s_l + \max\{0,z_l(s)\}}{1+\sum_{l=1}^L \max\{0,z_l(s)\}}
$$
Then $z$ being continuous implies that $f$ is continuous.

Is this obvious (to someone who, unlike me, understands continuity and is good at recognizing continuous functions)? If not, to show it would/could I just use the epsilon-delta definition of continuity?

Normally, I would think of $f$ as a function composition or something, but the fact that there is a $\max$ is throwing me off.

Thanks

Also, $\triangle^{L-1} = \{s \in \mathbb{R}_+^L \mid s_1 +\dots +s_L = 1\}$ denotes a simplex.

Comment: What do you mean by $z_l$? How is $f_l$ related to $f$?

Comment: The $l$'th component of $z$.

Comment: Projections are continuous, $\max$ between two continuous functions is continuous, sums of continuous functions are continuous, quotients of continuous functions are continuous and constant functions are continuous.

Comment: Okay, I see now.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I did not realize that max (between two continuous functions) is continuous. That helps, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the composition of continuous functions and is thus continuous.